# Why I get error message 404 not found when I try to delete Item

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a problem since I am a beginner in ASP.NET MVC; I try to create a `Delete` method using AJAX call on button click.

When I press Delete button, I get an error "404 Not found". I follow the tutorial which I found but I can not delete item from Index Page.

I create this controller action method:

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    Patient patient = db.Patients.Find(id);
    db.Patients.Remove(patient);
    db.SaveChanges();

    TempData["success"] = true;
    TempData["result"] = "Patient Has Been Successfully deleted";

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

In my `Index` page I add action name

```
<div class="panel panel-flat">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table datatable-responsive datatable-patients">
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-blue">
                    <th>
                        Firstname
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Lastname
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Contact
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Email
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Blood Group
                    </th>

                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr id="tr-id-@item.patient_id">
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.patient_first_name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.patient_last_name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.patient_contact_number)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.patient_email)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.patient_blood_group)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <ul class="icons-list text-right">
                                <li class="text-primary-600"><a href="~/Patients/Edit?Id=@item.patient_id"><i class="icon-pencil7"></i></a></li>
                                <li class="text-danger-600"><a class="delete_pacient" href="javascript:;" data-id="@item.patient_id"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                        @*<td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.patient_id }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" })
                                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.patient_id }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger"  })
                         </td>*@
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in my script I create this function

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_pacient', function () {
   var myId = $(this).attr('data-id');
   console.log(myId);
   var parent = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
   swal({
            title: "Are you sure?",
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#FF7043",
            confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        },
        function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/Patients/DeleteConfirmed",
                    data: { id: myId },
                    success: function () {
                        parent.fadeOut('slow', function () { $(this).remove(); $('.child').remove() });
                        setTimeout(function () { swal("Deleted!", "Record deleted successfully!", "success"); }, 2000);
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        swal("Oops", "Something went wrong!", "error");
                    }
                });
            })
    });
```

Whenever I try to delete It only display message

```
 swal("Oops", "Something went wrong!", "error");
```

When I check in console, I see this error message

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Patients/DeleteConfirmed:1

Does anyone know where I made mistake ? What is wrong here ?

Comment: No, it is not. I tried

Comment: Sorry if I am wrong, but as I see in your snippet, you've set the ActionName("Delete") attribute for your Action. Maybe you have to call `/Patients/Delete` instead of `/Patients/DeleteConfirmed`?

Comment: No it is not. I see this kind of error and I change it to `/Patients/Delete` but still have problem

Comment: Please remove [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")], keep it simple [HttpPost] or change ActionName to DeleteConfirmed

Comment: What's the **name** of your controller class in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: PatientController

Comment: Thank you everyone. I solve the problem. Actually @SameeDaris comment was correct answer. I delete [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")] and know it works

Comment: if your controller name is PatientController then path should be "Patient/deleteconfirmed" not "patients/deleteconfirmed"

Comment: @don_julian please don't accept an answer that is incorrect. Post your own correct answer

Comment: @julian I wanted to say to change it to [HttpPost].    HttpPost and HttpGet are two different request methods. You have read about the usage and differences.

Comment: Yes, I get the point what I made wrong here. Thank you for you attention.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these ways?

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Folder_Name_Where_The_Index_Controller_Is");
```

This works only if the function is in the same file where this is called out.

```
return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
```

You can also use this

```
return Redirect("http://YourPage.com/Index);
```

If these did not help, replace the code with this:

```
public async ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Patient patient = db.Patients.Find(id);
            db.Patients.Remove(patient);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            TempData["success"] = true;
            TempData["result"] = "Patient Has Been Successfully deleted";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: I think the problem is in my AJAX call, not in Controller

Comment: I have had the same problem without AJAX. I also updated my post, you can try the code I changed for you.